# Prove: $\sin (3\pi/2 - x) = -\cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, special-functions

I know the sine of $3\pi/2$ is $-1$.

So i plug it in the function making it.
$\sin(-1-x) = -\cos x$.

However, I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Use $\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\sin(b)\cos(b)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Do you know that

$$\sin(\pi+x)=-\sin x$$
and
$$\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)=\cos x\qquad?$$

if NO, draw the trigonometric circle!